# Notation / terminology for the group of all radicals $\sqrt[n]{a/b}$ where $a,b,n$ are positive integers

Tags: group-theory, notation, terminology, radicals

$$\{\sqrt[n]{q}\;\mid\;n\in\mathbb N,\;n>0,\;q\in\mathbb Q,\;q>0\}$$
$$=\{2^{e_2}\cdot3^{e_3}\cdot5^{e_5}\cdot7^{e_7}\cdot11^{e_{11}}\cdots\;\mid\;e_i\in\mathbb Q,\;\text{finitely many }e_i\neq0\}$$

Multiplication in this group is just addition of the exponents for each prime. We can also define the GCD of any two elements by taking the minimum of the two exponents for each prime, and the LCM by taking the maximum of the exponents.

Is there a standard name or symbol for this group? I'm thinking of something like "the rational-radicals", $\sqrt[\mathbb N]{\mathbb Q}$ (though that suggests it includes all roots of unity).

For any positive integer $n$, and any Abelian group $G$, the $n$th power ($G\ni g\mapsto g^n\in G$) is a homomorphism, so the pre-image of any subgroup $S$ is also a subgroup, which could be denoted $\sqrt[n]S$. The union of all of these (varying $n$) is also a subgroup, which could be denoted $\sqrt[\mathbb N]S$. Here we can take $G$ to be the positive real numbers (or just the algebraic ones), and $S$ to be the positive rational numbers.

Comment: This group is (isomorphic to) the countably infinite direct sum of copies of the additive group of the rationals. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_sum_of_groups

Comment: Yes, but I'm considering it as a subset of the algebraic numbers in $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$, not just as an abstract group.

Comment: I know of no name for this. Some one may. For now, just define it as you have and choose a name.

Comment: One issue with your proposed notation ${}^\mathbb N\sqrt S$ is that it depends on $G$. For example, it makes a difference whether you think of $S = \mathbb Q^*_{>0}$ as a subgroup of $\mathbb R^*_{>0}$ or $\mathbb R^*$ or $\mathbb C^*$ etc. I would suggest not inventing a complicated notation for this subgroup, and instead just say something prosaic like "let G be the subgroup generated by...".

Comment: Due to ambiguity of roots of unity, the $n$th root notation in abstract fields can be delicate. You are working in the positive real numbers, so there isn't an issue. But in other settings it can be an issue and lead to errors. When a field $K$ contains all the $n$th roots of unity and $a \in K^\times$, then the notation $K(\sqrt[n]{a})$ is *not* ambiguous since it is the splitting field over $K$ of $x^n - a$ and such notation for a field extension is used in Kummer theory. But if $K$ doesn't contain all $n$th roots of unity then be very careful when speaking of "the" field $K(\sqrt[n]{a})$.